# Is a martingale conditioned to return in the future a supermartingale?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, martingales, stochastic-analysis

Let $M_t$ be a martingale on $\mathbb{Z}^d$ and assume $M_0=0$. Let $n \in \mathbb{N}$. For any $t \leq n$, let $Q_t^n$ be distributed as $|M_t|$ conditioned on $M_n=0$, where $|M_t|$ is some norm. Is $\{ Q_t^n \}_{1 \leq t \leq n}$ a supermartingale?